# Reason to use Cross_Val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I'm confused about the reason to use cross_val_score.

From what I understood, *cross_val_score* tells if my model is
'overfitting' or 'underfitting'. Moreover,it does not train my model.

Since I have only 1 feature, it is tfidf (sparse matrix). I don't know
what to do if it under/over fitting.

**Q1: Did I use it in wrong order? I've seen both 'cross->fit' and
'fit->cross' examples.**

**Q2: What did the scores in '#print1' tell me? Does it mean I have to train my model k-times (with the same training set) where k is the k-fold that give the best score?**

My code now:

```
model1=GaussianNB(priors=None)

score=cross_val_score(model1, X_train.toarray(), y_train,cv=3,scoring='accuracy')

# print1
print (score.mean())

model1.fit(X_train.toarray(),y_train)
predictions1 = model1.predict(X_test.toarray()) #held out data  

# print2
print (classification_report(predictions1,y_test))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) are some informations about cross-validation.

The order (`cross` then `fit`) seems fine to me.

First you evaluate the performance of your model on known data. Taking the mean of all the CV scores is interesting but maybe it would be best to leave the raw scores to see if your model doesn't work on some sets.

If your model works, then you can `fit` it on your train set and `predict` on your test set.

Training the same model `k` times won't change anything.

Comment: Now, I guess the evaluation help me tuning the parameter of classfier,right? And now I wonder about : What defines that my model work from evaluation (cross_cal_score)? And I use the same train set both in cross_val_score and fit model, is this ok?